# Why golems and avatara in Mausoleum didn't attack lord Momon?

Tags: overlord

In chapter 12 lord Ains (Momon) tells Albedo to

> hand over her ring to Pandora's actor because the golems and avatara will automatically attack anyone wearing the ring.

I don't understand why they didn't attack lord Ains himself and how can this improve security.

[image]

Comment: Ainz also took out his ring, the security measure is that he's the only one that knows about it, and since you need the rings to access the Mausoleum, if anyone were to steal a ring and get that deep he/she would just go inside while still wearing it

Comment: @paulnamida Please post as an answer instead